# lubuntu 22.04 LTS hiberate goes to suspend insted of shutdown

Tags: lubuntu, 22.04, hibernate

I installed lubuntu 22.04 LTS on my dell inspiron and I have windows 10 and using dual boot . I followed these links
(1. https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10/
2. [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405990/hibernate-entry-in-the-menu-on-22-04#:~:text=Check%20if%20hibernate%20works%3A%20Open,%2Flocalauthority%2F10%2Dvendor.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405990/hibernate-entry-in-the-menu-on-22-04#:%7E:text=Check%20if%20hibernate%20works%3A%20Open,%2Flocalauthority%2F10%2Dvendor.))

to enable hibernate and its working (the hibernate was disabled earlier ), but whenever I hibernate it hibernates(like wifi goes off ..monitor becomes blank for 2 seconds) and It shows a screen saver and asks for password and loads the desktop where I had left!!. looks like its just going to suspend mode.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks .

Comment: Please specify what you actually did; as those instructions you linked provide details that apply for GNOME that don't apply with Lubuntu which runs LXQt.

Comment: oh is it ... I am totaly new to ubuntu ...just followed all the steps till "Gnome extention " in first link and then   steps in Answer of second link . like editing /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla  and /etc/systemd/system/use-10_grub_common.service . and sudo systemctl enable use-10_grub_common ... all of them and rebooted thats it .

Comment: After 17-july-2022 full update ...the hibernate is just shutting down the system. After reboot its loading a blank desktop. :)