# Ubuntu 22.04 fails in returning after hibernate and hibrid sleep (wifi issue)

Tags: wireless, 22.04, hibernate

I reinstalled Ubuntu 22 because of some issues.

- I have a /home installed in a 2nd device;
- previously I have hibernation activated

Soon as the re-installation was concluded, I made small non-related configurations, like:

- installing chrome, LibreOffice,
- checking if anaconda works,
- verifying if all devices (beyond the 2ndary one with my home) were mounted in the correct location (otherwise correcting),
- setting swap file, etc.

I noticed the hibernation buttons were already available at startup menu, but not working.

I expected they would be excluded with the re-installation, but there were them. So,
I made the configurations to activate it… But what happens is:

- Both hibernate option at startup menu, or `systemctl hibernate` does not resume to  the prior session. It’s like I have shutdown.
- if I attempt Hybrid Sleep, it works partially. It resumes the prior session, but the Wi-Fi is not identified, as shown in this image:

[image: The Wi-Fi is not recognized]

No network, in fact, can be identified…

[image: No network]

I do not believe it is some issue with the Wi-Fi+Bluetooth card. It appears very stable, no issue during the usual use... just with this hybrid sleep.
The only way I manage to make it working back is by shutdown (restart is not sufficient).

The suspend works fine. No Wi-Fi issue.

---

**Additional Information:**

I do not remind all the procedures any more, but:

- The `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla` were modified like described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405990/hibernate-entry-in-the-menu-on-22-04);
- The `/etc/systemd/system/use-10_grub_common.service` ;
- and `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` also [as above link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405990/hibernate-entry-in-the-menu-on-22-04);
- The `/etc/default/grub` already contains, as indicated [here](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10/):

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash RESUME=UUID=[the UUID] resume_offset=[from swapfileinfo]"

- Also `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`
- I have not a swap partition, I use a swap file instead, and it is bigger than my RAM.

---

So, my question is: How to effectively activate hibernation in Ubuntu 22.04?

Any help is appreciated.